# EntityValue timeout

Tags: bugs, entity

**Bug in 12.1.1 and possibly earlier versions**

---

Acknowledged by WRI as an issue CASE:4617646.

```
$Version
(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Vegetables"]["Foods"];
```

Fails with

> EntityValue::ctimeout : A computation timed out.

This works

```
Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Dairy"]["Foods"];
```

Any workarounds? WRI was not able to provide one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue) determines the foods by finding the associated food types, and then finding the foods associated with each type, you can mimic this with:

```
dairy1 = Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Dairy"]["Foods"];
dairy2 = Union @ Flatten @ EntityValue[
    Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Dairy"]["FoodTypes"],
    "Foods"
];

Union @ dairy1 === dairy2
```

> True

So, you can obtain the foods associated with "Vegetables" using:

```
vegetables = Union @ Flatten @ EntityValue[
    Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Vegetables"]["FoodTypes"],
    "Foods"
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Carl.